# не находит картинку по относительному пути в инлайновом background-image

Tags: html, css, link, background-image

```
<img src="img/about-us1.jpg" alt="">

<div class="swiper-slide"style="background-image:url(img/about-us1.jpg)"></div>
```

---

не подключается картинка фоном, а просто через img - находит
уже час мучаюсь, перепроверил нейминг, путь, все виды ковычек

Comment: попробуйте пробел добавить перед style

Comment: добавил 2 ) - не помогло

Comment: ну еще можно пробел перед url и в одинарные кавычки взять картинку. А для начала проверить есть ли содержимое в .swiper-slide - если пустой и высота 0 фон бесполезен.

Comment: ёлки-палки - точно! swiper-slide  без размеров. спасибо огромное!